# How to translate JSON api specific fields with translation stored in DB

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, json, laravel

I buid a live score website using Laravel and React template, I use an API to get live data with json format like this :

```
[
{
    "country_id": "6",
    "country_name": "Spain",
    "league_id": "300",
    "league_name": "Copa del Rey",
    "league_season": "2020/2021",
    "league_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_leagues/300_copa-del-rey.png",
    "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/6_spain.png"
},
{
    "country_id": "6",
    "country_name": "Spain",
    "league_id": "302",
    "league_name": "La Liga",
    "league_season": "2020/2021",
    "league_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_leagues/302_la-liga.png",
    "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/6_spain.png"
},
```

And I do like that to get values :

```
$APIkey='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$country_id = 6;

$curl_options = array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/? 
action=get_leagues&country_id=$country_id&APIkey=$APIkey",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curl_options );
$result = curl_exec( $curl );

$result = (array) json_decode($result);

var_dump($result);
```

What I'm looking for is to do translations of some specific json fields before displaying it in frontend, I clarify my idea like that:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
        JSON file from API ======> make translations ===>displaying in view
                                             ||
                                             ||
                           getting translations words from database
```

for example `Copa del Rey` translate it to `Coupe du Roi` who this word stored in database in french language?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your question is too broad: Are you looking for advice on how to set up your own database that contains the translations? How to inject these translations into the result from `apiv3.apifootball.com`? How to perform the translation itself?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen the database setup is easy, the issue is the using of a third part app to make translation but all of them not free and very expensive, the second idea is to use a translation stored in database, but the question is how to do it in real time and when getting this from API and before displaying it in View...

Comment: I am assuming you have translation keys in the DB. When you get a response from the API, query the DB with the key you got from the API response. That way, you will get the stored value against that key from the DB and use that value to be shown on the front end.

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj the idea I had in mind but can you explain ideas with code in Laravel?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Laravel expert but if you want I can show this in Node js?

Comment: The API have a default unique language is English

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj Me too I'm not expert in node JS what I confirm is  that I use a react  dashbaord inf frontend!

Comment: Let me know if you want to know how this goes in NodeJS and ReactJS. I can make a sample for your reference.

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj Few days Im in this so I hope any solution if you can...

Answer (score 2):

**Approach**:

I am not assuming here that you have different translation files like **french_translations.json**, **spanish_translation.json**, etc. because your request is not to translate from `English` to some other language but vice-versa. So, ideally, your database model (file storage or any other storage) would like to have all the keys (in all the languages) and their **English** values

An example of such a model is below (assuming file storage here and the file name is **translations.json**):

```
{
  "Copa del Rey": "Coupe du Roi",
   ... // your rest of the `key-value` pairs
}
```

The live data you received from your DB is below:

```
live_data = [{
    "country_id": "6",
    "country_name": "Spain",
    "league_id": "300",
    "league_name": "Copa del Rey",
    "league_season": "2020/2021",
    "league_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_leagues/300_copa-del-rey.png",
    "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/6_spain.png"
},
{
    "country_id": "6",
    "country_name": "Spain",
    "league_id": "302",
    "league_name": "La Liga",
    "league_season": "2020/2021",
    "league_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_leagues/302_la-liga.png",
    "country_logo": "https://apiv3.apifootball.com/badges/logo_country/6_spain.png"
}]
```

In your API, you would do something like this:

```
import translation_list from 'translations.json'; // import the translation file

// Using the `map` operation, translate the desired key(s) 
// and return the result (`translatedLiveData`) to the client
translatedLiveData = live_data.map(item => {
  return {
   ...item,
   'league_name': translation_list[item['league_name']]
  }
});
```

Hope I can give you a better picture. Let me know if you need more understanding here.